# Xcode 6.4 Unity project dyld: symbol not found error

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, dyld

i'm getting this error when running my Xcode project in simulator

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _UP_ACAccountCredential_alloc_initWithOAuth2Token_refreshToken_expiryDate_
  Referenced from: /Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EE487FF8-61D9-4F6D-9B37-68B59E6EFD38/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DA009D88-B649-449E-B53F-107A97D29365/sling.app/sling
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EE487FF8-61D9-4F6D-9B37-68B59E6EFD38/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DA009D88-B649-449E-B53F-107A97D29365/sling.app/sling
(lldb)
```

Simulator goes black screen.

Thanks for any help, i'm Xcode newbie, it's my first day with it.

Comment: What version of iOS are you targetting?

Comment: in Targets -> Unity-iPhone -> Build Settings -> `Deployment is IOS 7.0 selected.

Comment: So how is an app targeting < iOS 8 supposed to use a third-party `.dylib`?  Support for embedded frameworks was only introduced in iOS 8.  I suspect you have left native library support turned on.

Comment: tried to run with IOS target 8.0, same error

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for the [ACAccountCredential](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountCredentialClassRef/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ACAccountCredential/initWithOAuth2Token:refreshToken:expiryDate:) class it may be an issue that you have not added the Accounts framework to the XCode project. This can be added by going to the Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries pane. Click the '+' button and search for Accounts and add it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was u3dxt plugin, works fine when removed.